# Photoshop Scripting: How to export PathItem by its name

Tags: javascript, vector, photoshop-script

I am desperately trying to figure out how to write a js for photoshop, that exports only a specific path and not all of the contained paths under the "paths" tab in my PS Document to an Illustrator File.
For example in the picture here:

[image: image of my paths tab]

I would like to export only the path with the Name : "2 Acryl" by using a script.
I already have a working script that exports all of the paths into one AI File.
I just can't figure out how to reference a single path by its name and export it.

```
function unSaved() {
try {
    activeDocument.path;
    /* Finish Unsaved Document Error Check - Part A: Try */

    /* Main Code Start */

    /* Based on the following topic thread:
    https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop/exporting-all-paths-to-illustrator-error/m-p/8796143 */

    var doc = app.activeDocument;
    var docPath = doc.path;
    var docName = doc.name.replace(/\.[^\.]+$/, '');
    var newFile = File(docPath + '/' + docName + '_Paths' + '.ai');
    var expOptions = new ExportOptionsIllustrator;
    expOptions.path = IllustratorPathType.ALLPATHS;
    doc.exportDocument(newFile, ExportType.ILLUSTRATORPATHS, expOptions);
    // alert('All Photoshop paths have been exported as a single Illustrator file in:' + '\r' + docPath);

    /* Main Code Finish */

    /* Start Unsaved Document Error Check - Part B: Catch */
} catch (err) {
    alert('An image must be both open and/or saved before running this script!')
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by altering the **ExportOptionsIllustrator** object according your needs.

```
 var expOptions = new ExportOptionsIllustrator;
```

To export a single path, the ExportOptionsIllustrator.path property must be set to

```
 expOptions.path = IllustratorPathType.NAMEDPATH;
```

After that you can pick your desired path by it's name using:

```
expOptions.pathName = '2 Acryl';
```

## Edit:

Apparently due to a bug in Photoshop itself the export option **IllustratorPathType.NAMEDPATH** is simply ignored. Photoshop will always export all paths no matter what.

Here's a hacky workaround though. Photoshop script offers the **PathItems** object which contains a list of all the paths in the document. So the idea is this:

1. create a clone of the current document
2. iterate over all the paths inside the clone
3. remove all EXCEPT for the single path you want to keep
4. export the clone's path as an Illustrator file
5. close the clone without saving

Here's the updated script:

```
try {
    var doc = app.activeDocument;
    var docPath = doc.path;
    var docName = doc.name.replace(/\.[^\.]+$/, '');
    var newFile = File(docPath + '/' + docName + '_Paths' + '.ai');
    var expOptions = new ExportOptionsIllustrator;
    
    var duplicate = app.activeDocument.duplicate('duplicate');
    
    for(a = duplicate.pathItems.length-1; a>=0; a--)
    {
        if(duplicate.pathItems[a].name != '2 Acryl')
        {
            duplicate.pathItems[a].remove();
        }
    }
    
    duplicate.exportDocument(newFile, ExportType.ILLUSTRATORPATHS, expOptions);
    duplicate.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
    
} catch (err) {
    alert('An image must be both open and/or saved before running this script!')
}
```

## Edit2:

If this still fails, there's a last resort. Photoshop has a built-in function to export paths to Illustrator. Simply go to:

File * Export * Paths -> Illustrator...

and choose your desired path in the popup dialog.

Comment: Hi, thank you first of all I was really trying for ages how passing a path Name works, now I know how to do that :) Unfortunately it is still exporting all paths to one AI file. Do you have an idea what could be the problem ?

Comment: Hi obsure, thanks again for your effort :) The script works fine until the end the problem ist that it doesnt export the path once there is "2 Acryl remaining" instead it exports the drawing surface. I tried setting expOptions.path = IllustratorPathType.ALLPATHS;
but it doesn't change anything. Somehow it seems to take DOCUMENTBOUNDS instead of ALLPATHS

Comment: Actually I can't tell you why it ain't working Ludwig. I just retested the script with an additional layer of art and all it exported was the path. Did you copy & paste the script as is? Well, there's one more way to get paths from Photoshop. Take a look at my updated answer.

Comment: Hi Obscure,I figured out the problem:
after exporting the path out of the duplicate document i deleted the line of code which deletes the duplicate ps file right away. I think the problem was that it closed the file before it could export properly. Probably a delay before closing would work as well. 
Thank you very much for your help I really appreciate it :)

Comment: Hey Ludwig! Glad you got it sorted and I could help! =)
By the way, if you think the above is the right answer please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the Record:  [@obscure](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6504633/obscure)s first answer edit works well. In case it doesn't work with the exact code, try adding delay after:
`duplicate.exportDocument(newFile, ExportType.ILLUSTRATORPATHS, expOptions);`

before closing the ps file, or just don't execute the line of code that closes the ps document.

Thanks again !